# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & Radeon Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm having a problem with the drivers of my R7 M265 Graphic Card.

I've read on the web that Ubuntu 16 won't support Radeon Drivers, but that there are some Open Source drivers integrated in but, when I for example run the command:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

The Output is:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation
>   Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)

Can anyone help me make my Radeon recognized by Ubuntu?

Thanks.